# Is it possible to record/screenshare on a kvm (with qemu) virtual machine to a host without a capture card

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, desktop-recording

I'm getting a pc today and I'm interested if it's possible to screenshare to (on discord) the virtual machine's screen to a host if i use kvm. I use linux now but my computer is nowhere good enough for me to be able to test it so I'm here to ask if it's 1. it's possible and 2. how to do it. preferably without a capture card or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can share the guest with any swoftware that can share/record windows or sections on your screen.
I've used `recordmydesktop` to capture videos of guests as well as sharing them via [google meet](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ie/products/meet).

I can't tell you how to do things in discord, but from a qemu/kvm perspective just use [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/) or [virt-viewer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/virt-viewer.1.html) to view your guest which will give you a window which inside holds what the guest thinks is the full screen.

Then use your screen sharing/recording software to share that window or that area of your overall desktop.